# Python regular expressions over several rows (multiline) in depending of Row 1

Tags: python, regex, multiline

I have a log (txt file) with following structure.

```
At 2020-07-15 14:05:18 - Markers detected in this frame : 3 | 6 | 
ID :6 out of compartment G2A44
```

or

```
At 2020-07-15 14:05:47 - Markers detected in this frame : 3 | 0 | 9 | 
ID :9 out of compartment G2A13
ID :9 out of compartment G2A45
```

See [regex](https://regex101.com/r/5WX3TZ/1/).

I need the information of

1. 2020-07-15 (group1)
2. 14:05:47 (group2)
3. ID :9 (group4)
4. G2A13 ...

When I have only 1 line below `At 2020-07-15 14:05:47 - Markers detected in this frame : 3 | 0 | 9 |` everything will be caught with the expression
`expr = 'At ([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}) - Markers detected in this frame : ([0-9]{1,} .{1,})\s(ID..[0-9])\sout of compartment ([\w]{4,})'`.

But how can I get a second or third line with with the same group matching in regex?

```
import re
expr = 'At ([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}) - Markers detected in this frame : ([0-9]{1,} .{1,})\s(ID..[0-9])\sout of compartment ([\w]{4,})'
f = 'XX.txt'
file = open(f,'r')
text = file.read()
m = []
m = re.findall(expr,text, re.MULTILINE)
print(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for a parser. You need a state machine.

Test the target line based on the header expression, and store some values. If it doesn't pass that test, then test the line based on the next expression, and do something with the new matches and the stored values.

Do not expect to get all the lines at once. This is a two-phase job.

Comment: Thanks Chad.That is the confirmation I need.

Comment: A comment is not the normal way to show you like the answer.